# Everytime I deploy react webapp, when I open it in my phone there appears a white screen

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nginx

I have created a web app in reactjs. When I deploy my app to the server, sometime the screen appears white for the first time after deploy. When I reload the page the app runs normally. Why is this white screen coming just after the deploy? I am using nginx server on azure to host the backend and frontend files.

I tried many optimisations in react. White screen frequency has reduced but it has not gone completely

Comment: Check the browser console on your phone for the error message. Depending on the type of phone and browser the process to access the browser console / devtools is different, it's best to google it. [This is how to do it for Chrome on Android, for example.](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/)

Comment: because of your phone web cache, react after compiling with webpack changed file names, but you phone cached url, need reload to fix

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this to disable caching

## Nginx config

```
location ~ \.html$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
        add_header Expires "Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT";
        add_header Pragma no-cache;
    }
```

## Html headers

```html
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```